# How can I compare OLS, Ridge, and Lasso with R-squared values?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, r-squared

I've run three regression algorithms with $X$ of size about $100\times100$ and $y$ of size about $100\times1$, using Matlab.

One is ordinary OLS, another is ordinary Ridge, and the other is Lasso.

The results are obtained as

- $R^2$ of OLS, Ridge, Lasso are $1$, $0.85$, $-0.06$, respectively.
- $R^2$ of OLS, Ridge, Lasso using $5$-fold cross validation scheme are $0.85$, $0.83$, $-0.05$, respectively.

With these values, what and how can I compare the $R^2$ values of the above three models?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: how do you get negative $R^2$? Something is wrong with the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can compare them because $R^2$ is model-independent.

But you have to be careful about $R^2$ because it is computed on your training data, so that it might be over-optimistic and could fool you sometimes.

I advise you to test your models on a validation dataset and compute Relative Mean Square Error or $Q^2$ (the equivalent of $R^2$ on validation set)

Comment: As $R^2$ is large, can I say  that model is better than the others? For exmaple, in my case, OLS is the best, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in this case, it is. But I advise you to confirm this first insight by computing it on a validation data set (i.e. an held-out set)

Comment: I have only 100 by 100 input matrix with 100 by 1 output vector. So,  firstly, I ran OLS (used pseudoinverse cause input matrix is not full rank) and got $R^2_{OLS}=1$, ran Ridge with $\lambda=10$ and got $R^2_{Ridge}=0.85$, and finally ran Lasso (which is performed by internal function, lasso, in MATLAB) and got $100$ numbers of $R^2_{Lasso}$'s, so I chose the minimum $\lvert{R^2}\rvert$ value, which is $-0.05$. Is this process correct?

Comment: And then, I used $5$-fold cross validation scheme, divide 100 by 100 input matrix, $A$, into $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5$, each of them is of size 20 by 100. Then, I test five times (in $i$-th iteration, $A_i$ is test set and the others are training set), and then coefficients of regression function output having the least squared error is chosen as optimal model.

Comment: @Danny_Kim, note that $R^2$ calculated out of sample is not a sensible performance measure because it completely ignores bias. If the real values are 1,2,3 and your model predictions are 101,102,103, the $R^2$ will be 1, even though the predictions are awfully biased. Also, 1,2,3 and -101,-102,-103 would yield the same, which is even worse ($R^2$ ignores the sign of correlation between true values and their predictions)...